# No Checkbox to" Restart Jenkins when installation is complete".Unable to restart Jenkins post plugin download

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have set up Jenkins version (ver. 2.155).

post adding plugin, i need to restart Jenkins but "Restart Jenkins" tab or link not working. I don't find my [] checkbox to check/tic click on arrow is not working (Refer image). Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: GETTING MESSAGE AFTER TRYING TO RESTART "Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured." wHAT SHOULD I DO NOW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restart Jenkins manually, you can use either of the following commands (by entering their URL in a browser):

`(jenkins_url)/safeRestart` - Allows all running jobs to complete. New jobs will remain in the queue to run after the restart is complete.

`(jenkins_url)/restart` - Forces a restart without waiting for builds to complete.

Comment: I've always thought they should have named 'safeRestart' to 'restart' and the 'restart' command to 'forceRestart'. It seems dangerous to have restart be the less safe option, but thats just me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can restart jenkins by visiting `/restart`. So if your url is `https://my-jenkins.local` you would visit `https://my-jenkins.local/restart`.

It's been answered many times before, so maybe search around next time ;). Hope that helps ya.